# Openvswitch setup with Mitaka, unable to ping interfaces

Tags: networking, openstack

With a new Mitaka setup we encounter a problem in relation to Openvswitch.

The setup is as following for the "OVS Classic" setup (refer to doc "Networking"):

- Set of hosts (Ubuntu 14.04LTS) on same LAN with each main bond interface with 3 VLANs on top for the target architecture;
- KVM VMs for Controller, Network and Compute nodes (Ubuntu 16.04LTS) over bridges on top of VLANs, networking works fine, VMs can ping hosts.
- In Network node whilst configuring the OVS bridge, for example with the vs br-tun bridge we are unable to ping hosts. This is done after removing the IP address form the VS port and allocating it to the vs bridge. tcpdump seems to indicate a layer 2 problem. Although this seems to be a common problem with OVS bridges, after Googling around we can't figure out what is wrong.

I hope someone can point us in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be OVS on Ubuntu 16.04 not working out of the box. Ran into the problem with another installation, which worked after the creation of bridges but not after a reboot.

What needs to be done is to follow this great life saving post related to Ubuntu 16.04: [Boot integration of the Openvswitch in Ubuntu](http://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=240) and then strictly follow the guidance  of the README.Debian.gz file from /usr/share/doc/openvswitch-switch to configure bridges and ports in the /etc/network/interfaces. Below an excerpt of the file.

```
Examples:
--------
ex 1: A standalone bridge.

allow-ovs br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    ovs_type OVSBridge

ex 2: A bridge with one port.

allow-ovs br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    ovs_type OVSBridge
    ovs_ports eth0

allow-br0 eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    ovs_bridge br0
    ovs_type OVSPort

ex 3: A bridge with multiple physical ports.

allow-ovs br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    ovs_type OVSBridge
    ovs_ports eth0 eth1

allow-br0 eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    ovs_bridge br0
    ovs_type OVSPort

allow-br0 eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    ovs_bridge br0
    ovs_type OVSPort
```

Note that options can be combined, I have myself a setup of OVS bridges on the top of linux bridges which seem to work fine.

This way setup will survive a reboot in Ubuntu 16.04 (and Openstack will fully work).